# Injective endomorphism of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a field. If $\phi:F\rightarrow F$ is an injective endormorphism, can we conclude that $\phi$ is an automorphism?

Since $\phi$ is injective, we have $F\cong \phi(F)$.  This implies that $\phi$ is surjective.

In many reference books, $F$ is assumed to be finite. But the above proof also holds when $F$ is infinite. Can anyone point out the mistake I made?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Namely, consider the map $\Phi:\Bbb Q(X)\to\Bbb Q(X)$, $\Phi(f)=f(X^2)$.

"$\phi(F)\cong F$ implies that $\phi$ is surjective" is the mistake.

Comment: You mean that $image(\phi)\cong F$ does not imply $image(\phi)=F$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I said. It is entirely possible for algebraic objects to contain copies of themselves, if some finiteness or rigidity property of sort does not intervene.

Answer (score 0):

$\Phi$ is not necessarily an automorphism.  But interestingly enough, it is always injective.

Comment: A homomorphism of fields always preserves the multiplicative neutral element, so it is never trivial. For many people the same holds for rings, for opinions differ whether rings are expected to have a multiplicative neutral element. Those who include it in the definition also assume that it is preserved under homomorphisms. I am not aware of a book that would not expect a field to have a $1$, again preserved by homomorphisms. The notion strikes me as silly.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok.  I should have kept in mind that it was an endomorphism.  A homorphism from a field to a ring is injective or trivial.

Comment: Not to me (nor to many other algebraists, like Jacobson, van der Waerden etc who insist that a homomorphism of rings preserves $1$)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ok. Point taken.